# problem with LuaLaTeX: no file found

Tags: miktex, luatex, luaotfload

I am trying to experiment with lualatex but I cannot make it work properly

My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[greek]{polyglossia}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

and my editor (texmaker) is configured to  lualatex+pdf

When I compile my document I do not get any error message, only an empty pdf is produced and I get a pop-up message: "file not found"

The corresponding log file is:

LOG FILE :

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011080216 (rev 4277) (format=lualatex 2014.9.4) 4 SEP 2014 10:47
**Eξετασεις13_14Στατιστικη_sample.tex
(C:/Users/Manthos/Desktop/LaTeX/Eξετασεις13_14Στατιστικη_samp
le.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8l-luatex-1.4> and hyphenation patterns for engl
ish, loaded.
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty"
Package: polyglossia 2014/05/21 v1.33.5 Babel replacement for XeLaTeX and LuaTe
X
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/misc/etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count87
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count89
File: xkeyval.tex 2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex")))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty"
Package: fontspec 2011/02/26 v2.1f Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2014/07/20 v5241 L3 programming layer (loader)
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2014/07/20 v5241 L3 programming layer (code)
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2014/05/26 v4889 L3 Bootstrap code
L3 Module: l3names 2014/06/02 v4993 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2014/07/09 v5187 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2014/06/16 v5146 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2014/07/17 v5214 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2014/06/19 v5158 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2014/07/18 v5232 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2014/07/11 v5197 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count90
\l_tmpa_int=\count91
\l_tmpb_int=\count92
\g_tmpa_int=\count93
\g_tmpb_int=\count94
L3 Module: l3quark 2014/05/26 v4889 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2014/05/04 v4728 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count95
L3 Module: l3clist 2014/07/19 v5237 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2014/05/26 v4889 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2014/07/17 v5215 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2014/05/30 v4943 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2014/07/09 v5188 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count96
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count97
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count98
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count99
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count100
L3 Module: l3skip 2014/07/17 v5211 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2014/06/12 v5121 L3 Key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count101
\l_keys_choice_int=\count102
L3 Module: l3fp 2014/07/18 v5223 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count111
L3 Module: l3box 2014/05/31 v4974 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
L3 Module: l3coffins 2014/05/28 v4899 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
L3 Module: l3color 2014/04/30 v4712 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3candidates 2014/07/18 v5232 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.
def
File: l3unicode-data.def 2014/06/30 v5166 L3 Unicode data
)
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
File: l3pdfmode.def 2014/07/18 v5232 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count112
))
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse
.sty
Package: xparse 2014/07/20 v5241 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count113
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count114
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count115
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count116
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count117
)
(C:/Users/Manthos/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/generic/binhex/binhex.tex)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty"
Package: luaotfload 2011/04/21 v1.25 OpenType layout system
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty"
Package: luatexbase 2010/10/06 v0.3 Module utilities for LuaTeX
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-compat.sty
"
Package: luatexbase-compat 2010/10/10 v0.3 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-loader.sty
"
Package: luatexbase-loader 2010/10/10 v0.3 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.loader.lua)
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-regs.sty
"
Package: luatexbase-regs 2010/10/10 v0.3 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-attr.sty
"
Package: luatexbase-attr 2011/05/21 v0.31 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/attr.lua))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-cctb.sty"
Package: luatexbase-cctb 2010/10/10 v0.3 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/cctb.lua)
\lltxb@catcodetable@alloc=\count277
\CatcodeTableIniTeX=\luatexcatcodetable1
\CatcodeTableString=\luatexcatcodetable3
\CatcodeTableOther=\luatexcatcodetable5
\CatcodeTableLaTeX=\luatexcatcodetable7
\CatcodeTableLaTeXAtLetter=\luatexcatcodetable9
\CatcodeTableExpl=\luatexcatcodetable11
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-mcb.sty"
Package: luatexbase-mcb 2010/10/10 v0.3 Callback management for LuaTeX
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-modutils.s
ty"
Package: luatexbase-modutils 2010/10/10 v0.3 Module utilities for LuaTeX
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua))
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/mcb.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-mcb 2010/05/12 0.2 register several functions in a callb
ack
))
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs.lua)
Lua module: lualibs 2011/01/20 0.96 Lua additional functions.
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-string.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-lpeg.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-boolean.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-number.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-math.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-table.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-aux.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-io.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-os.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-file.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-md5.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-dir.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-unicode.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-utils.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-dimen.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-url.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-set.lua)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua)
Lua module: luaotfload 2011/04/21 1.25 OpenType layout system.
luaotfload: loading file C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfloa
d/otfl-luat-dum.lua.
quiting: fix your readable cache path
```

any ideas?

Comment: Your version of `luaotfload` is quite old. Try fully updating MiKTeX.

Comment: Update your system with the update manager (admin). Beside this: don't use inputenc and ucs with lualatex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved with a software update